# When does the cachemodel in ibatis re-query the database to get updated records?

Tags: ibatis

I'm using ibatis and its cache model for the first time and i cant seem to figure out at what time will the cache be filled with new results, meaning whne will the query that i'm applying cache model on be executed again to fill the cache with new results.
Does it require some sort of command to get the results again or will it be done automatically? any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will be filled again when it is flushed which is done over events such as fluchoninterval, flushOnupdate, flushoninsert.

Answer (score 0):

along with the above answer, you can also define flush intervals. You can define the flush interval in hours, mins & seconds and let the flush happening every x hours, y mins, z seconds interval.